# PostgreSQL: Syntax Error At or Near TO

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to grant permissions for a function to a user

```
postgres=# grant all privileges on function myfunction to a_user;
```

But I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to"
LINE 1: grant all privileges on function myfunction to a_user;
```

Any reason why?

My function starts like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction(
param_val1 varchar(255),
param_cal2 VARCHAR(255), 
param_val3 VARCHAR(255),
param_val4 current_category,
param_val5 current_type,
param_val6  VARCHAR(255),
param_val7 bigint,
param_val8 text )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include the function signature, not just the name. In this case, if `myfunction` has zero parameters, it would be like this:

```
grant all privileges on function myfunction() to a_user;
```

**EDIT**

Seeing that the function does take parameters, the signature would be this:

```
myfunction(character varying, character varying, character varying, <rest of parameters>)
```

Comment: what if it does have parameters? Do you include the name and type?

Comment: @Eli only parameter types are required, for instance, `myfunction(integer, boolean)`, but you can also include the name. You can see the complete reference [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it works:

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA schemaname TO a_user;
```